# Django template adding javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm trying to add javascript static file in to my html. But i couldn't

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>SpaceX</title>
<script src="static/js/script.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="static/img/img.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

Image is working correctly but the JS is not

Url:

```
 from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path, include
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('spacex/', include('spacex.urls'),
             )
    ]
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Script

```
alert('abc') ;
```

Setting:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

And on powershell

```
[28/Dec/2019 19:12:20] "GET /spacex/ HTTP/1.1" 200 166
[28/Dec/2019 19:12:20] "GET /spacex/static/js/script.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

Saying like that so what's the problem can you help me ?

Comment: Please don't link to images of code. Include all the code in the question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [staticfiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/) app template tags

```
{% load static %}
<script src="{% static "js/script.js" %}" ></script>
```

Comment: Hello when i try this it says like that :  Invalid block tag on line 7: 'import'. Did you forget to register or load this tag? Furthermore, i can implement css files withhout {% static 'css/styles.css'%} i just write this href="static/css/styles.css" and it works

Comment: Sorry I used "import" instead of "load".  Try it with the updated answer?

Comment: Oh yeah it worked I thank you very much ! I'm trying to this stuff for 2 hours do you know any good documentation about django?  i dont have enough reputation to vote up you :(

Comment: The tutorial from the Django docs is pretty useful https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/